# what is happening in this update of php code for Ext js

Tags: javascript, php, extjs

Actually new in Ext js  I m trying to find a solution for this code. I mean i want to see success is true and first "if" block is working but unfortunatelly else block is working and getting false 
Why?

```
public function update() {
    $res = new Response();

    if (!get_class($this->params)) {
        $res->data = array();
        foreach ($this->params as $data) {
            if ($rec = Event::update($data->id, $data)) {
                array_push($res->data, $rec->to_hash());
            }
        }
        $res->success = true;
        $res->message = "Updated " . count($res->data) . " records";
    } else {
        if ($rec = Event::update($this->params->id, $this->params)) {
            $res->data = $rec->to_hash();
            $res->success = true;
            $res->message = "Updated record";
        } else {
            $res->message = "Failed to updated record " . $this->params->id;
            $res->success = false;
        }

    }
    return $res->to_json();
}
```

Comment: Well, this is not an ExtJS specific question. Anyway, PHP cannot go int both `if` and `else` blocks at the same time so if `success:false` then it must go into the first else and then to the second else.

Comment: i solved this problem. in extjs side javascript call this php file and try to reach Event::update function but it couldnt